# Forwarding current compiler to ExternalProject

Tags: cmake, external-project

I was trying to use [ExternalProject](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/ExternalProject.html) module:

```
ExternalProject_Add( googlebenchmark
                 GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/google/benchmark.git"
                 TLS_VERIFY ON
                 CMAKE_CACHE_DEFAULT_ARGS -DBENCHMARK_ENABLE_TESTING:BOOL=OFF
                 SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/third_party/gbenchmark"
                 INSTALL_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/third_party" )`
```

And there is an issue I've come up with:
this module for some reason doesn't forward compiler, used in (parent) cmake, as well as CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.

I've tried to use CMAKE_CACHE_DEFAULT_ARGS to set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER directly, but it didn't quiet worked out.

Is there a decent explanation for this behaviour?
Is there a proper (cmake-ish) way to forward currently used compiler/build configuration to ExternalProject?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To forward the compiler use the `ExternalProject` argument `CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS`, i.e.:

```
ExternalProject_Add( googlebenchmark
    ...
    CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS 
       "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}"
       "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}"
)
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! Actually, ExternalProject uses Regexps to parse parameters to options, so you need to append type for those variables (FILENAME).

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the types. The correct type is actually `FILEPATH`.

Comment: `CMAKE_ARGS` can be used without the type (it's passed to the inner `cmake` as regular cmdline parameters). `CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS` is only needed if the cmdline becomes too long, which is probably relatively rare.