# cmake ExternalProject_Add and setting CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER with project() command

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

I'm trying to build a multi-project project with cmake, and have used the `ExternalProject_Add()` command. However, I can't get the `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` option to stick, which causes the following problem: During configure, the external project checks for several compiler capabilities, setting (or not setting, in this case) a necessary flag in a .h file. When I run make, a different compiler is used, and the values in the .h file are incorrect.

I've boiled it down to the following lines of code, which occur at the top of my `CMakeLists.txt` file for the external project (CGAL):

```
message("**** CXX Compiler is ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
project(CGAL CXX C)
message("**** CXX Compiler is ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
```

When I run this, the first message displays the correct value (the Frameworks compiler installed through XCode). However, the second message shows the wrong compiler (GNU version I've installed with MacPorts). I've looked up the [project](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/project.html) specifications, but they are quite sparse. They do note that, without including the `project()` command, an implicit one will be added with the `CXX` and `C` languages. Sure enough, when I remove the `project()` command, both messages report the wrong compiler.

Is there something I don't know about the `project()` command? Does it search for a `CMakeLists.txt` file somewhere in the filepath and load it by default? Is there a way I can overload this setting (something short of creating a temporary variable to hold the old value)?

FWIW, [setting `CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32744788/forwarding-current-compiler-to-externalproject) doesn't work.

Comment: Which compiler are you wanting to use? A quick fix might possibly be to edit your .bash_profile temporarily to disable the macports export path.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm trying to get the build to work for other users. Also, setting "export PATH=[Frameworks bin path]:$PATH" doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Turns out the problem was that I was including `BUILD_COMMAND ${make}`, which was running make with no additional arguments.

Comment: I know this is an old quesiton, but out of curiosity, why were you running `make` instead of using `cmake --build`? And why was running `make` without more parameters bad? Shouldn't cmake have configured make to tell it where to find the compilers you told it to use?